# Visual Studio Embedded Crystal Report Keeps Prompting Database Login?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ado.net, crystal-reports

I'm using visual studio 2005 to develop a form with a combobox passing a value into the parameter of an embedded crystal report.  I'm trying to figure out why it keeps prompting me for a database login every single time you try to run the report with a different combobox selection.

Here is my code:

```
private Sub Form1_load... 
        Dim ConnName As String
        Dim ServerName As String
        Dim DBName As String
        Dim user As String
        Dim pass As String
        Dim gDBA As ADODB.Connection
        Dim records As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim datver As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim query As String


        '---OPEN THE DATABASE CONNECTIONS
        gDBA = New ADODB.Connection ': gDBA.CursorLocation = adUseServer
        'Added to prevent time out error
        gDBA.CommandTimeout = 1000 : gDBA.ConnectionTimeout = 1000

        gDBA.ConnectionString = "Server=svr13;Database=subscribers;User ID=KViews;Password=Solution;Trusted_Connection=True;"

        gDBA.Open("Data Source=Kaseya;Initial Catalog=subscribers;User Id=KViews;Password=Solution;", "KViews", "Solution")

        records = New ADODB.Recordset

        query = "select distinct groupname from _v_k order by groupname desc"
        'records.ActiveConnection = gDBA.ConnectionString
        records.CursorType = CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly
        records.LockType = LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly

        records.Open(query, gDBA)
        Do While Not records.EOF
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(records.Fields("groupname").Value)
            records.MoveNext()

        Loop
end Sub 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim selected As String
        selected = ComboBox1.Text

        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("C:\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\CrystalReport1.rpt")
        cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("KViews", "Solutions", "svr13", "subscribers")


        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("companyname", selected)

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    End Sub
```

I looked at this previous posting [database login prompt with crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132314/database-login-prompt-with-crystal-reports)

but this wasn't very helpful.  I couldn't find where a CMC was to disable the prompt.

Any ideas?  thanks in advance

Comment: So it doesn't prompt you when you first run the report, but then prompts you when you change the combo box's selection to run the report again?

Comment: it prompts me both times.. when I first attempt to run it and again when I choose a different combobox value to run again.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. the following line was incorrect

```
    cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("KViews", "Solutions", "svr13", "subscribers")
```

it should just be this:

```
    cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("KViews", "Solutions")
```

the login prompt doesn't show up anymore.