# Prevent login of ODBC Text driver in Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, odbc

I am new to Crystal Report and I have a problem I cannot figure out.
Because I cannot find an answer anywhere I try it this way.

I am using a Crystal Report which uses an ODBC database with a text driver as a datasource.
This report works perfect when opening it with the standalone Crystal Report XI.

When opening it via VS2010 over a basic c#-program I am always prompted for the Username and Password for this DB, in spite there is none of this.
Because of this I cannot access the data.

The strange thing is, that it is possible to access the data of the fields via "Browse Field Data" in the editor.

Is there something I am missing?

```cs
namespace CrystalReportsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string reportPath;
        private ReportDocument repDoc = new ReportDocument();
        private FileInfo m_AssemblyCS;
        private DirectoryInfo m_SolutionRoot;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_AssemblyCS = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            m_SolutionRoot = m_AssemblyCS.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent;
            reportPath = string.Empty;
        }

        private void bOpenReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = m_SolutionRoot.FullName;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "rpt files (*.rpt)|*.rpt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            { 
                reportPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                tbReportPath.Text = reportPath;
                repDoc.Load(reportPath);
                crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = repDoc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Unfortunately the se hasn't helped. I still get the error. I tried to following:

```cs
private void bOpenReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
  openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = m_SolutionRoot.FullName;
  openFileDialog1.Filter = "rpt files (*.rpt)|*.rpt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  { 
    reportPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    tbReportPath.Text = reportPath;
    repDoc.Load(reportPath);

    foreach(Table table in repDoc.Database.Tables)
      SetConnectionInfo(table.Name, "dds", "", "", "");

    crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = repDoc;
  }
}

private void SetConnectionInfo(string table, string server, string database, string user, string password)
{ 
  TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
  logOnInfo = repDoc.Database.Tables[table].LogOnInfo;
  ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
  connectionInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

  connectionInfo.DatabaseName = database;
  connectionInfo.ServerName = server;
  connectionInfo.Password = password;
  connectionInfo.UserID = user;
  repDoc.Database.Tables[table].ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
}
```

The connectionInfos of the tables are set, but I still get the login-dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answer of the following question:
[How do I change a Crystal Report's ODBC database connection at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674363/how-do-i-change-a-crystal-reports-odbc-database-connection-at-runtime)

We normally supply the connection credentials via the "Part2" mentioned there using 
CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo object.
Normally you do not have user/password on text files so maybe providing empty/empty works.

Looks like there is another question where the guy had the same issue and solved it as follows: 
[visusal studio embedded crystal report keeps prompting database login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602015/visusal-studio-embedded-crystal-report-keeps-prompting-database-login)

Comment: Your last link helped. Crystal Report seems to need a need a called SetBaseLogon with dummy-values for the UserName and PassWord. So something like "repDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("UserName", "UserPW");" after loading the report does the trick. Thanks for you help!