# Crystal Reports prompts login only on other PC

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports, report

I made a small VB.NET application which includes a Crystal Report. Running the Crystal Report on the machine I made it works perfectly. When I run the application on my laptop, the Crystal Report always prompts me for a login eventhough the database has no login set to it. I have tried passing in "Admin" and "" with code, but no luck.

I'm working with an Access database, this is the code I have to load my Crystal Report:

```
If frmReport Is Nothing OrElse frmReport.IsDisposed Then
  frmReport = New frmReport
End If

frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = "../../Reports/Klantenbeheer.rpt"

frmReport.MdiParent = Me
frmReport.Show()
```

I did look at [Prevent login of ODBC Text driver in Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385784/prevent-login-of-odbc-text-driver-in-crystal-report-for-visual-studio-2010) but I'm not sure if it applies to my situation?

I also tried setting the rpt's datasource to the datasource I work with in the application and then assigning that to the ReportSource, but no luck either.

Some people found a solution in changing from DAO to OLEDB, but I have used OLEDB from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code found in [at the bottom of this thread](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1569879) could help you? Specifically:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Dim myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
Dim myReport As New ReportDocument()
myReport.Load(Server.MapPath("ReportName")) 'name of your Crystal Report - see note below

Dim myTables As Tables = myReport.Database.Tables

For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
Dim myTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
myConnectionInfo.ServerName = <SQL servername>
myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "" 'leave database name blank
myConnectionInfo.UserID = 'login name
myConnectionInfo.Password = 'password
myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo)
Next

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport
```

It is made for ASP.Net, but might work with minor adjustments?

Comment: I tried a similar approach by looping over myTables and setting the location of each of them to my Access database. Unfortunately this throws a COMException.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it's an old question. But I think I should just add an info that, I got a link that, after painful research, he tell that, we must copy the correct version of crdb_ado.dll. Read it here : [XtremeNetTalk](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=81509). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate that file yet in the internet! I hope I can complete this answer with this.