# Crystal reports, why is it asking for database login even after I provided the details?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am generating a report, but the problem is even though I've supplied credentials, when the form containing the CrystalReport opens up, it still asks me for them, and the worst part is, I don't enter any thing in there, and just click finish, and it loads the report. So, if there is no need for credentials (or whatever) why is it asking me?

Here's the code

```
    private void MainReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var constr = string.Empty;
        constr = Application.StartupPath;
        if (Generate.bForProjects)
            constr = Path.Combine(constr, @"Reports\Projects.rpt");
        else
            constr = Path.Combine(constr, @"Reports\Other.rpt");

        var myConInfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo();
        reportDocument1.Load(constr);
        myConInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "ProjectData.mdb";
        myConInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Data\ProjectData.mdb";
        myConInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "";
        myConInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "";
        reportDocument1.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(myConInfo);

        reportDocument1.Refresh();

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument1;
        crystalReportViewer1.Width = this.Width - 50;
        crystalReportViewer1.Height = this.Height - 100;
    }
```

When the form loads, this screen pop ups

[image]

**And, when this comes up, I don't enter anything! That's right! I just click finish and it loads the report perfectly! So, if it doesn't needs anything, why the hel* is it asking me for a login?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have lots of problems when we came to connect a crystal report to a different database to the one it was designed / created against. We ended up creating the following  function to set it up correctly. It recursively sets the connection on all report tables and sub reports.

Also I seem to remember we had problems if the report was designed with Integrated Windows Authentications, and run with a simple username and password. So we always made sure we designed the reports with a simple username and password connection to the database.

```
private static void SetConnection(ReportDocument report, string databaseName, string serverName, string userName, string password)
{
    foreach (Table table in report.Database.Tables)
    {
        if (table.Name != "Command")
        {
            SetTableConnectionInfo(table, databaseName, serverName, userName, password);
        }
    }

    foreach (ReportObject obj in report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects)
    {
        if (obj.Kind != ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
        {
            return;
        }

        var subReport = (SubreportObject)obj;
        var subReportDocument = report.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName);
        SetConnection(subReportDocument, databaseName, serverName, userName,  password);
    }
}

private static void SetTableConnectionInfo(Table table, string databaseName, string serverName, string userName, string password)
{
    // Get the ConnectionInfo Object.
    var logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
    var connectionInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

    // Set the Connection parameters.
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
    connectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
    connectionInfo.Password = password;
    connectionInfo.UserID = userName;
    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);

    if (!table.TestConnectivity())
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(Resource.UnableToConnectCrystalReportToDatabase);
    }

    table.Location = Database + "." + "dbo" + "." + table.Location;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this methods you created and they don't work. It continues asking me for the old database, it never changes. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It only appears when your DataSet or DataTable is empty.  So make sure it has data.

Comment: From "Database Expert" option, I have removed all the tables from dataset which are not being used in report. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just create report object and add below link
rptobj is crystalreport object and setdatabaselogin is method which take user id and password as a parameter.

`rptobj.setdatabaselogon(userid,password)`

Answer (score 1):

Include -->  SetDatabaseLogon

Works great - added that 1 line [  SetDatabaseLogon  ]  and now everything works!

Note: connecting to MariaDB 10.3

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        string the_report = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
        //cryRpt.Load("D:\\CrystalReports\\feedback.rpt");
        cryRpt.Load(the_report);

        cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("xyz", "123");

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        // set up crystal parameters
        //crystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = false; //removes the toolbar
        crystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = 0;  //removes the Group Tree on the Left
        crystalReportViewer1.ShowLogo = false;
        // end set up crystal parameters
        //crystalReportViewer.Zoom(50); crystalReportViewer.RefreshReport()
        crystalReportViewer1.Zoom(1);   
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

        //generate the filename
        string dt_stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
        //parse the report filename from combobox drop down
        string lastFragment = comboBox1.Text.Split('\\').Last();

        string create_file = "E:\\CrystalReportsSent\\"+ lastFragment.Replace(".rpt","") +"--" + dt_stamp.ToString() + ".pdf";
        //MessageBox.Show(create_file.ToString());
        pdfFile = create_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132314/database-login-prompt-with-crystal-reports/60676636#60676636) regarding older version of SQL Native Client saved with the report file and disabled, insecure encryption protocols such as TLS 1.0 that causes what *appears* to be a login failure.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code will help.

```
internal static TableLogOnInfos GetLogOnInfos()
    {
        string server = DatabaseHelpers.DbHost;
        string database = DatabaseHelpers.DbName;
        string userID = DatabaseHelpers.DbUser;
        string password = DatabaseHelpers.DbUserPass;
        string table = DatabaseHelpers.DbTableName;
        TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = database;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = userID;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password;
        logOnInfo.TableName = table;

        return new TableLogOnInfos{logOnInfo};
    }
```

Then on page load and on crystal designer report refresh event, you can use this .

```
 private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{
reportTopCustomersRpt1.SetDatabaseLogon(DatabaseHelpers.DbUserPass, DatabaseHelpers.DbUserPass).
crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = CrystalReportManager.GetLogOnInfos();
}
private void crystalReportViewer1_ReportRefresh(object source, CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ViewerEventArgs e)
{
// did not help
// reportTopCustomersRpt1.SetDatabaseLogon(DatabaseHelpers.DbUserPass, DatabaseHelpers.DbUserPass);
crystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo = CrystalReportManager.GetLogOnInfos();
}