# Crystal report asking username and password

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

Every time I open my form that has a crystal report it always ask for username and password but i did not even use a username and password in my web application. I use integrated security in my web.config. How can I fix this problem?

This is code:

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
            using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
            // FOR CRYSTAL REPORT
            using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
            using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Configuration;

            // FOR SQL CONNECTION
            using System.Data.Sql;
            using System.Data.SqlClient;
            using MediCard_Cooperative.App_Data;

            namespace MediCard_Cooperative.MediCard_Cooperative.Reports
            {
                public partial class rptTest : System.Web.UI.Page
                {
                    private SqlConnection connSQL;

                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
                        dsMembers ds = new dsMembers();                     // .xsd or dataset filename
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        // Set the name of data table
                        dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Members";
                        dt = getAllData();                                  // calling 'getAllMembers' function
                        ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);

                        // .rpt file path "../Reports/SimpleReports.rpt"
                        rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("../Reports/CrystalReports/ctrSample.rpt"));

                        //set dataset to the report viewer
                        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                        ctrViewerTest.ReportSource = rptDoc;
                    }

                    public DataTable getAllData()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (connSQL = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connstring"].ToString()))
                            {
                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Test", connSQL))
                                {
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                                    connSQL.Open();
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                                    {
                                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                                        da.Fill(ds, "dtTest");

                                        return ds.Tables[0];
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: you need to pass server credentials through code.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to mention the database username and password through the `ReportDocument` object.

```
rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password);
```

Comment: but i don't have a username and password. I did not even use that in the whole project

Comment: @anonymizer: If you're using SQL Authentication to connect to your database, then you must be having a username and password. Check the "connstring" value in your application config file. Otherwise if you're using Windows Authentication to connect to database, then you can try out sajanyamaha's answer.

Answer (score 1):

it is unable to find the dataset or the dataset used to design the report is different from the dataset passed, crystal report assumed you need to log in.

since you are not passing parameter to your sp, i think it would be better to directly let crystal report manage those. lesser code to maintain.

Comment: use the dataset you created (the one used to design the report) in your code behind.

Comment: It is very surprising that you have explained the main point very well but no one voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass server credentials through code

```
rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(yourDatabaseServerUsername, yourDatabaseServerPassword);
```

something like

```
rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "123");
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473407/crystal-reports-why-is-it-asking-for-database-login-even-after-i-provided-the-d

Comment: it seems you are using windows authenticated SQL Server(ie without userbane and password),Try change your report using OLE DB (ADO) -> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server -> check on Integrated Security.also see http://forums.asp.net/t/1712704.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

Open your crystal Report in C# or VB whatever you are using 
Then
Go to
Field Explorer
and Right Click on Database Fields
Like
[image]

And Select Set Datasources Location...

A new Window will open...
Expand the properties.

[image]

Then Find the integrated Security 
It will Be False by default Change it to True

Like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Dim myreport As New PurchaseInvoiceTest`
'Crystal Reports asks for authentication every time issue resolved by below line
`myreport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "abcdef@12345")`

Answer (score 0):

BE SURE to set your Datasource Location in Crystal:

1. When using OLEDB (ADO), set.
2. Select "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"

[image: Set Datasource Location Image]

Answer (score -1):

`rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sureguide_admin", "ejaz661")`

ts working