# What if ms-access asks for uid and password unnecessary?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am using ms access as database and i don't have any uid and password.
even if so while running crystal report it asks for uid and password.
and for every entry, it says "logon failed".is there any internal setting for this?

Comment: According to this http://vbcity.com/forums/t/116596.aspx, it is to do with your initial set-up, but elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473407/crystal-reports-why-is-it-asking-for-database-login-even-after-i-provided-the-d) it suggests that you do have to supply a username and password. For MS Access, the user name Admin and a blank password will usually work, though whether it will work with Crystal Reports is another question.

Comment: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Ideal_payment\ideal-payment.accdb".  this is my connection string.Admin and blank password i sn ot working.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a login and password, any dummy credentials may be enough to bypass the error. Look at this link for examples:

[How to open a secured Access database in ADO through OLE DB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191754)