# Crystal Reports .NET (main and subreport with different database)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm working on a Visual Studio project that shows Crystal Report in web application.

There are two same reports with same titles and names but different data
 like `[db1].[dbo].[xxx]` and `[db2].[dbo].[xxx]`. 
Databases are same but records are different and when I use connection string it only shows records on `db1` on both reports.

Is there any way to show data from 2 different databases in 1 report file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for generating report using one database at a time, then its easily possible. Look for similar implementation as this link. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/270977/Change-the-Data-Source-of-a-Crystal-Reports-Report

[Creating Crystal report with C# and Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816713/creating-crystal-report-with-c-sharp-and-sql-server)

If you are trying to connect 2 databases same time to generate single report then its quite difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried the first one and it's working like charm. And yes i am trying to connect 2 databases at the same time in my report view.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer/voting up.